# How to get a chosen element's event with event.target?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of paragraphs, and when the paragraph is clicked (not hovered) I want it to highlight. Currently all the paragraphs get highlighted when any one is clicked on, but what I really want is to apply highlight only to the paragraph I click. I tried `event.currentTarget` but it is giving me an error.

```
<p class="pon" ng-click="para($event)"> Paragraph one </p>
<p class= "pon" ng-click="para($event)"> Paragraph two </p>
```

Here is the angular:

```
$scope.para = function(event){
angular.element(event.currentTarget)(document.getElementsByClassName('pon')).css('background-color', 'green')  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the style of the clicked element use:

```
$scope.para = function (event) {
    var elem = angular.element(event.target);
    elem.attr('style', "background-color:green")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful.